# How to make JAXB unmarshaller use getters rather than fields

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have some classes generated automatically using [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and [jaxbfx](https://github.com/buschmais/jaxbfx). The latter generates JAXB classes with getters and setters that should be called when marshalling and unmarshalling respectively. However, the JAXB marshaller and unmarshaller methods use fields instead of the getters and setters.

The following code shows an example of a class generated with jaxbfx.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyType")
public class MyType{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    protected int id;
    private final transient IntegerProperty idProxy = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public void setId(int value) {
        this.id = value;
        this.idProxy.set(value);
    }


    public short getId() {
        return this.idProxy.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return this.idProxy;
    }
}
```

Therefore, I would like to know whether it is possible to make the marshaller and unmarshaller use the getters and setters instead of the fields. Please note that I cannot change the JAXB annotations manually, since they are generated automatically.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I have remarked that I'm using XJC to generate my Java classes, so I cannot change the JAXB annotations by hand, as described in the post you mention (and other posts I have already checked before posting my question)

Comment: I am the author of the [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin]. My plugin does not modify getters and setters to achieve "a very specific behaviour".  So you're either omitting important details or misinterpres something. Show more code, show what you get, maybe the you'll get help.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Doesn't look like a duplicate for me.

Comment: @lexicore I was referring to the ( [jaxbfx](https://github.com/buschmais/jaxbfx) ) plugin when I said that is was generating setters and getters with a specific behavior. I has rewritten the question and added a code snippet to better describe the issue.

Comment: @magomar Ok, looks better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution follows:

Modify the [jaxbfx](https://github.com/buschmais/jaxbfx) to clear all JAXB annotations from generated classes: this is achieved by invoking method `clearAllAnnotations(implClass)` for every class to be generated

Install the the [jaxb2-basics-annotate](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-annotate) plugin.

Modify the xml schema (file.xsd) to add the @XmlElement annotation to any getter and setter method.
 For example:

```
   <xs:complexType name="MyType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <annox:annotate target="setter">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute(required=true,name="id")
                    </annox:annotate>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
```